# please give reason(s) to move comments to chat

Tags: discussion, support

Today comments under a question were moved to chat within a couple of hours, but there are older posts with many comments on the main site.

Can a reason be given for moving comments to chat?

Comment: [it's simply how the system works at this time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93444/provide-a-tool-for-moderators-to-migrate-comments-to-chat/237976#237976)